# PDFKit Watermark Annotation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I'm playing around with Apple's PDFKit and I'm using their [sample app for adding a watermark](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Document-Watermark.zip) to a pdf document.

The code works as expected apart from one pdf that I have. This particular pdf will not allow the annotation of the watermark to occur.

I have edited the pdf so that it no longer has an owner but still no annotation. The only thing I can think of is that the version of this pdf is 1.7 all other versions of pdf that I tried were previous to 1.7.

Has anyone else had this problem when working with the latest PDFKit framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the properties of PDF if changes are permitted and document is not locked

You can check the properties by

Print(document.islocked),
Print(document.ischangesallowed)
Etc